# form submit always hit in mvc index method while enable unobtrusive javascript enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-javascript

MY form element submit is not working while enable unobtrusive javascript mode. it always hits in index method. how to resolve this issue. while enable unobtrusive mode with form submit successfully.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var Data = value;
  ViewBag.dataSource = Data;           
  return View();
}

public ActionResult frmbtn()
{
  return View("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public void Formposting()
{
  // it not hit while  enable unobtrusive in webconfig 
  . . . 
}
```

Comment: "unobtrusive javascript mode" ??

Comment: You need to show your view code

Comment: Unobtrusive Js sounds like a red herring. Please post your view code.

Comment: Also why the down-vote? Just because he/she is asking a newbie question?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show view code it's difficult to locate the problem. you can match your code with given below:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Formposting", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formid" }))
    {
    }
```

Donot forget to replace "ControllerName" with actual controller name.

Or if you have blank in beginform like below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    }
```

You need to add one more "Action" with httppost and model

```
    public ActionResult Index(Your Model Here){  return View();}
```